# Access LG4 Android Phone That Loops

Tags: android, lg

Having just returned from holiday my LG G4 phone decided to go wrong. It switched off and then restarted but doesn't get past the logo screen. Every so often a screen pops up says optimising apps. Then nothing. I only install apps I need and remove stuff I never use, so the phone isn't full of gaming apps etc.

I have tried getting to safe mode but it will not so that either. It appears that it may need to go back to LG via Vodafone for repair.

The problem for me is that having just returned from holiday I have a number of photos on the phone which I would like to transfer to my PC. However as I cannot accees the the phone I cannot activate MTP so the pc cannot see my files and folders.

Is there a work around for this?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

If you have pictures in sd card then you can transfer it via a card reader.
I think  your phone is stuck in a boot loop .Try to search in youtube for Fix android phone BootLoop . If not worked then press power+home+volumeup and after entering to recovery find option clear cache and press it and reboot

Hope it helps

Comment: Photo's are on the phone. Cannot get it to do anything. If  I press and hold volume keys etc I get a white screen with a bar code and IMEI number on, that is all

Comment: I have watched the video before. Sadly I have not been able to fix this issue and the phone was sent back as of yesterday.

Thanks for your input

Dave